# PiHole and OpenVPN not working: tun0 doesn't even exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn, raspberry-pi, pihole

I installed OpenVPN and PiHole. It works independently, but not together. I want to block stuff that comes through OpenVPN.

I tried the official guide. But in my case (Ubuntu server for Pi), there is not even a tun0 (it returns nothing).

https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/vpn/openvpn/setup-openvpn-server/

I don't even understand what a tun0 is and where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: tun0 is the first tunnel, because counting starts at zero https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/donald_knuth.png & https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/81wqic/what_exactly_is_the_purpose_of_the_tun0_interface/

Comment: Have you started the OpenVPN service? `systemctl start openvpn` and, for autostart at boot, `systemctl enable openvpn` https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/openvpn-tun0-missing-4175636204/

Comment: I can use OpenVPN normally. But there is no tun0, if I do the ifconfig command as described in my provided link

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig -a` (Without -a, ifconfig does not show inactive interfaces.) ?

Comment: thank you, with this command, I found tun0. I want to add: I saw that it also displays as "welcome message", when I log in via SSH

Comment: Sounds like tun0 does exist, but it fails to connect because of a misconfiguration and then becomes inactive.